# Get rows in between hours with SQL

Tags: sql

I have thousands of records (rows) that contain a time column.

I can easily get rows with time's in between 4 AM and 5 AM by doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(Time AS TIME) BETWEEN '04:00' and '05:00'
```

To get the rows between 6PM and 4AM:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(Time AS TIME) BETWEEN '18:00' and '04:00'
```

Gives me zero rows..

How can I do this?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(Time AS TIME) >= '18:00' OR CAST(Time AS TIME) < '04:00'`? Are you looking for a generic query that works both ways?

Comment: You could avoid the implicit time conversions; `datepart(hour, time) between 4 and 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(Time AS TIME) NOT BETWEEN '04:00' AND '18:00'
```

The values to `between` (and `not between`) need to be in order, with the smaller value first.  Otherwise, nothing will match.

The expression:

```
x between a and b
```

is exactly equivalent to

((x >= a) and (x <= b))

Comment: Hey that is clever! Thanks! Will accept when possible

Comment: "*The values (...) need to be in order*" - not if you use `between symmetric`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I hadn't heard of that.  It is specific to Postgres.

Comment: It is actually specified in the SQL standard. But as far as I can tell, Postgres and HSQLDB are indeed the only two DBMS implementing it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Cool.  I didn't realize it is in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Casting a time to a time is strange, but I assume it's actually a Timestamp :-)

You might also use EXTRACT:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Time) >= 18
  AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Time) < 4
```